# Replacing href dynamic tag in python (html body)

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a script that generates some body email from a dataframe to then send them to every user.
The problem is that my content is dynamic and so the links I am sending to every user (different links for different users)

The html body of the email is like:

```
<table border="2" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th style = "background-color: orange">AF</th>
      <th style = "background-color: orange">Enlaces Forms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>71</td>
      <td><a href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uIG64v4DfECWMjVIRUVBVjVBSCQlQCNjPTEkJUAjdD1n" target="_blank">https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uIG64v4DfECWofS8D1EufUjVIRUVBVjVBSCQlQCNjPTEkJUAjdD1n</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td><a href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uIG64v4DfECWofS8D1EufU4jQyVDREMk4zOSQlQCNjPTEkJUAjdD1n" target="_blank">https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uIG64v4DfECWofS8D1EufUVVGWFRUNjQyVDREMk4zOSQlQCNjPTEkJUAjdD1n</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am replacing html tags like this:

```
table2=df[['AF','Links']].to_html(index=False, render_links=True, escape=False).replace('<tr style="text-align: right;">','<tr style="text-align: center;">').replace('<table border="1"','<table border="2"').replace('<th>','<th style = "background-color: orange">').replace(f'<td><a href="{enlace}"','<td><a href="LINK"')
```

but I do not know how to make it work for the tag **"href"**.
My goal is to rename the hyperlinks with some words to make them more readable in the body mail.

How can I do that?

EDIT:
When I try to implement jinja2 Template:

```
import jinja2
from jinja2 import Template
temp2='<a href=""> </a>'
linkdef=Template(temp2).render(url=f"{enlace_tabla['LINKS']}",enlace="Flask")
            table2=enlace_tabla[['AF',linkdef]].to_html(index=False, render_links=True, escape=False).replace('<tr style="text-align: right;">','<tr style="text-align: center;">').replace('<table border="1"','<table border="2"').replace('<th>','<th style = "background-color: orange">')
```

The following error is raised:

```
KeyError: '[\'<a href=""> </a>\'] not in index'
```

Comment: See jinja2 template lib

Comment: I tried to implement it. See my edit please

Comment: I would replace data with `<a>` in DataFrame before `to_html()`. OR I would send  DataFrame directly to jinja template  (without `to_html`) and use `for`-loop to generate rows in table.

Comment: example with Template is totally wrong - you use `linkdef` as column name in `enlace_tabla[['AF',linkdef]]` but you should replace value in columns `LINKS`. you could use `.apply()` to run function which get value from `LINKS` and returns string generate with f-string like `f'<a href="{url}">{text}</a>'`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in different way.

First I would create column with `<a href="{url}">SOME TEXT</a>`

```py
def convert(row):
    return f'<a href={row["LINKS"]}>CLICK THIS LINK</a>'

df['LINKS_HTML'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

If I would have column with text for every link then it could be

```py
def convert(row):
    return f'<a href={row["LINKS"]}>{row["TEXT"]}</a>'

df['LINKS_HTML'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

And later I would render table using column `LINKS_HTML` instead of `LINKS`
(and without `render_links=True`)

```py
html = df[['AF', 'LINKS_HTML']].to_html(escape=False, index=False)
```

---

Minimal working example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'AF': [1, 2, 3], 
    'LINKS': [
        'https://httpbin.org/get?arg=101',
        'https://httpbin.org/get?arg=102',
        'https://httpbin.org/get?arg=103',
    ], 
    'TEXT': ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#print(df)

def convert(row):
    #return f'<a href={row["LINKS"]}>CLICK THIS LINK</a>'
    return f'<a href={row["LINKS"]}>{row["TEXT"]}</a>'

df['LINKS_HTML'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
 
html = df[['AF', 'LINKS_HTML']].to_html(escape=False, index=False)

print(html)
```

Result:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>AF</th>
      <th>LINKS_HTML</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href=https://httpbin.org/get?arg=101>Text 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href=https://httpbin.org/get?arg=102>Text 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><a href=https://httpbin.org/get?arg=103>Text 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Or I would use `jinja2` to generate table without `to_html()`

```py
import pandas as pd
import jinja2

data = {
    'AF': [1, 2, 3], 
    'LINKS': [
        'https://httpbin.org/get?arg=101',
        'https://httpbin.org/get?arg=102',
        'https://httpbin.org/get?arg=103',
    ], 
    'TEXT': ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

template = '''<table border="2" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th style="background-color: orange">AF</th>
      <th style="background-color: orange">Enlaces Forms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {%- for index, row in data.iterrows() %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ row["AF"] }}</td>
      <td><a href="{{ row["LINKS"] }}">{{ row["TEXT"] }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {%- endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
'''

html = jinja2.Template(template).render(data=df)

print(html)
```

Result:

```
<table border="2" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th style="background-color: orange">AF</th>
      <th style="background-color: orange">Enlaces Forms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="https://httpbin.org/get?arg=101">Text 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="https://httpbin.org/get?arg=102">Text 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><a href="https://httpbin.org/get?arg=103">Text 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```